# Python decorators passing attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm using decorators to enhance some methods, but I'm suffering from the lack of interoperability between them.

As an example, let's say I want to use the `functools.cache` decorator to memoize the results and a hand-made decorator to count the number of calls to that method:

```
from functools import cache, wraps
from typing import Callable


def counted(func: Callable) -> Callable:

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        setattr(wrapped, "calls", getattr(wrapped, "calls") + 1)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    setattr(wrapped, "calls", 0)

    return wrapped


@counted
@cache
def func_a(data):
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_a(1)
    func_a.clear_cache()
    print(func_a.calls)
```

The code, as it is shown, fails at the `func_a.clear_cache()`, because the `counted` decorator did not pass the methods/attributes that `cache` added to the function. If we swap the two decorators, then the `print(func_a.calls)` will fail because the `cache` decorator did not pass the attribute `calls` that was set by the inner decorator.

Is there a pythonic way to get a final function that contains every bit that has been added by the decorators?

I know I can modify the `counted` decorator to explicitly pass the `cache`-added attributes, but the issue comes when you are using two or more third-party decorators.

Comment: Does it work if you switch the order of the decorators?

Comment: I get an `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear_cache'`

Comment: @Barmar if I switch the decorators, then the missing attribute is `func_a.calls`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch yes, I know. That's precisely the issue. How to get a chain of decorators to pass thru all the attributes added by the innermost decorators. In this specific example, `counted` decorator does not pass the `clear_cache`, `cache_info` and `cache_parameters` attributes set by `cache` decorator.

Comment: The basic problem is that a decorator defines a new function. The attribute is on the inner `wrapped` function.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to propagate it out when you have multiple decorators.

Comment: I fully understand the issue and where the attributes are defined and stuck. But I was expecting to have some standard way to propagate those attributes. I cannot be the only one that hit that issue! Decorators are quite old, so for sure many people hit that problem :-(
In particular, knowing where the issue is located, allows me to tailor a hand-made decorator for a specific instantiation to pass the attributes (although this is an issue for the type checkers). But when dealing with third-party decorators, then I cannot do anything to solve the issue.

Comment: The `setattr` calls are made that way to avoid the type checker to complain. It would had been easier and cleaner to just access those attributes: `wrapped.calls = 0` is more readable than `setattr(wrapped, 'calls', 0)`. But the former causes an attribute-not-defined error in the type checkers.
In any case, that's another issue for another question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoration is just syntactic sugar for passing some callable (function or class) to another callable (the decorator) and that syntax is restricted to class/function definition statements.

Given some decorator `dec`, writing

```py
@dec
def f(): ...
```

is equivalent to this:

```py
def f(): ...

f = dec(f)
```

It is also important to stress that nothing inherently special is happening by virtue of decoration. The following is totally valid (albeit not very useful):

```py
def dec(_): return 1

class Foo: pass

@dec
class Bar: pass

def f(): pass

@dec
def g(): pass

print(Foo)  # <class '__main__.Foo'>
print(Bar)  # 1
print(f)    # <function f at 0x7fdf...>
print(g)    # 1
```

This goes to show that there is nothing magical about decoration leaving some sort of "trace" on the output of the decorator.

The `Bar` class and the `g` function are essentially consumed by the `dec` function and since no reference to them is returned by it, they are no longer in any way available after this decoration.

There is also nothing inherently special about returning *functions* from a decorator:

```py
def f():
    return "There is no spoon"

def dec(_func):
    return f

@dec
def g():
    return "Hi mom"

print(g.__name__)  # f
print(g())         # There is no spoon
```

Again, the decorator is just a function and in this case it returns another function, but nothing in this process does anything magical (or anything whatsoever) with the function `g`. In this example it is basically lost after decoration.

To get to an example more representative of real-world scenarios, decorators are usually written such that they *do* preserve something about the callable being decorated, but this typically just means that a wrapper function is defined inside the decorator and inside that wrapper the original callable is called.

```py
def dec(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func() + " There is no spoon."
    return wrapper

@dec
def f():
    return "Hi mom."

print(f.__name__)  # wrapper
print(f())         # Hi mom. There is no spoon.
```

The reference to the original function `f` is not lost, but it is inside the local namespace of the `wrapper` returned by `dec` and there is no way of getting to it anymore.

All of this is to drive the point home why there is no magical built-in way to somehow "preserve" any attributes of the callable being decorated. You need to take care of this yourself, if you want your decorator to do that. The same way you would have to write that kind of logic for any other function that takes some object as its argument, if you expect some attribute of that object to be present in the output of that function. And if you are using someone else's function and they *don't* do that, you are out of luck.

[`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) addresses this by giving us a quasi-standard pattern for writing decorator-wrappers, that keeps an explicit reference to the object being decorated in the `__wrapped__` attribute of the wrapper. But nothing *forces* you to use that pattern and if someone doesn't, again, you are out of luck.

The best thing thing you could do is to write (yet another) custom decorator that *relies* on other decorators using `functools.wraps` (or `functools.update_wrapper`) to recursively propagate everything from the chain of wrapped objects to the top-wrapper. It could look something like this:

```py
from functools import wraps

def propagate_all_attributes(func):
    wrapped = getattr(func, "__wrapped__", None)
    if wrapped is not None:
        propagate_all_attributes(wrapped)
        # Add attributes from `wrapped` that are *not* present in `func`:
        for attr_name, attr_value in wrapped.__dict__.items():
            if attr_name not in func.__dict__:
                func.__dict__[attr_name] = attr_value
    return func

def dec1(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        return func() + " There is no spoon."
    wrapper.x = 1
    wrapper.y = 2
    return wrapper

def dec2(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        return func() + " Have a cookie."
    wrapper.y = 42
    return wrapper

@propagate_all_attributes
@dec2
@dec1
def f():
    """Some function"""
    return "Hi mom."

print(f.__name__)  # f
print(f.__doc__)   # Some function
print(f.x)         # 1
print(f.y)         # 42
print(f())         # Hi mom. There is no spoon. Have a cookie.
```

But again, this will not work, if one of the decorators below it does **not** (properly) set the `__wrapped__` attribute on the object it returns.

That approach would of course allow for additional customization, like e.g. telling your decorator, *which* attributes to "pull up" from the wrapped object or which to *exclude* or whether to overwrite attributes set by later decorators with those of inner objects etc..

Assuming you are always able to check the source of third-party decorators you use, you could at least get some of what you are looking for this way, by applying it to decorators that correctly utilize the `@wraps`-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and explanation. I already knew almost everything you explained and I even developed a quite similar decorator to pull the inner attributes to the outer shell. But I was expecting some standard "batteries included" method to perform this action, like the `functools.wraps` method to facilitate the whole decorating process. Unfortunately, it does not exist and everyone needs to develop its own solution. I'm also surprised that nobody has written a package that includes this kind of functionality. I cannot be alone! XD